# How to insert msg box for runtime error handling in VBA for MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error, recordset

My code works fine if something is selected from the drop down and macro is run.

But if nothing is selected, which should never be the case, I get runtime error Invalid column name.

Instead, I want a msg box to say "Ensure X is selected from Drop Down" with OK button, instead of said runtime error.

The error occurs on below line which I found on debug:

rs1.Open sqlstrSchemeDetail, DBCONT

The error occurs because a sql string cannot be created if nothing is selected.

```
Call connectDatabase

rs1.Open sqlstrSchemeDetail, DBCONT  'WHERE ERROR HAPPENS

'Debug.Print sqlstrSel
Debug.Print sqlstrSchemeDetail

For intColIndex = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs1.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next

Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1

'rs.Close
'Set rs = Nothing

Call closeDatabase
```

This is the DBCONT

```
Public Function connectDatabase()
Set DBCONT = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim sConn As String
sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=PamwinPlusLIVE;Data Source=GS1NHHMSQLV04\INST04;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=SL1NHHMCTXV108;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

 DBCONT.Open sConn
 DBCONT.cursorlocation = 3

End Function
```

Further More

```
Dim sqlstrSchemeDetail As String
sqlstrSchemeDetail = "Select scheme.SchemeID, DevOfficer.Description [Scheme 
Owner], scheme.Description [Scheme Description], scheme.Version [v.], 
Status.Description [Status], TenureType.Description [Tenure Type], 
Template.Description [Template], Units.Units,scheme.lastupdatedDate 
[Updated] from scheme inner join Status on scheme.Status = status.StatusID 
inner join TenureType on scheme.TenureTypeID = TenureType.TenureTypeID inner 
join DevOfficer on scheme.devofficer = devofficer.devofficerid inner join 
SelScheme ON Scheme.SchemeID = SelScheme.SchemeID  inner join Template on 
scheme.TemplateID = template.templateid inner join (select 
scheme.SchemeID,sum(units) as Units from Property inner join scheme on 
Property.SchemeID = scheme.SchemeID group by scheme.SchemeID) Units on 
Units.schemeid = scheme.schemeid where scheme.masterSchemeID is null and 
SelScheme.SelID =" & GG

Dim GG As String
GG = Split(Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value, "-")(0)
```

GG returns an ID if something is selected from the drop down box and the code will then work. If nothing in the drop down box is selected, GG is some text which makes the code fail on
     rs1.Open sqlstrSchemeDetail, DBCONT

Comment: You need to show us how `DBCONT` is being created. That is where you need to validate

Comment: You can use: `On Error Resume Next` just before the line with error. Then: `On Error Goto 0`, just after the line. Then check error code: if it's not **0** then you have an error and you can display the `Msgbox' (make sure you set the error code to **0**). Although , I would catch the error much earlier

Comment: Is `DBCONT` the name of your dropdown - i.e. do you store your connection strings in the dropdown? If so (why?) then just wrap the code in `IF DBCONT <> "" ... <your code> ... Else Msgbox "Error " .. End If`. However, more likely is `DBCONT` is built from some predefined text that inserts the relevant string when you choose the dropdown. If so, the easiest way is again, wrapping but testing the value in the dropdown for a blank, instead of `DBCONT`.

Comment: Siddharth-rout, please see DBCONT

Comment: @Zac Note that the check of the `Err.Number` needs to be before `On Error Goto 0` because `On Error Goto 0` clears the error so you cannot read it anymore.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: well spotted.. had skipped my mind :)

Comment: What about `sqlstrSchemeDetail`? Is this what gets the value from the dropdown? If yes, can I see how ?

Comment: Yes is does get its value from the combobox. Please see above added detail.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom error handling label.

```
sub main()

    on error goto found_error
    Call connectDatabase
                    rs1.Open sqlstrSchemeDetail, DBCONT  --WHERE ERROR HAPPENS
                    'Debug.Print sqlstrSel
                    Debug.Print sqlstrSchemeDetail
                    For intColIndex = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
                    Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs1.Fields(intColIndex).Name
     Next

                    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1

     'rs.Close
      'Set rs = Nothing
     Call closeDatabase

    exit sub

found_error:
    msgbox err.number & chr(10) & err.description & chr(10) & sqlstrSchemeDetail & chr(10) & sqlstrSel

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. As advised, I caught the error earlier. I did this by saying if sqlstring = x then MsgBox y and exit sub, else continue open recordset...

```
If GG = "2. Select Selection" Then
MsgBox "Please Pick a Selection"

Exit Sub

Else Call connectDatabase 'Debug.Print sqlstrSel

            rs1.Open sqlstrSchemeDetail, DBCONT

           ' Debug.Print sqlstrSchemeDetail
            For intColIndex = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
            Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = 
rs1.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next

            Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
End If
```